# JS: Convert Today's Date to ISOString() with Fixed Time

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to convert today's date to an ISO standard string but with the fixed time of `T00:00:00.000Z`.

I can get as far as returning a ISO string of today's date and time:

```
var isoDate = new Date().toISOString();
// returns "2015-10-27T22:36:19.704Z"
```

But I wanted to know if it's possible to have a fixed time, so it should return:

```
"2015-10-27T00:00:00.000Z"
```

Is this possible?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: By "today", do you mean "the current date in the user's local time zone", or do you mean "the current date in Universal Time (UTC, GMT, etc.)"?  They won't always be the same.

Comment: Sorry, I mean local.

Comment: So you want the *local* date, but at the *UTC* midnight.  Why?

Comment: Because I need to use this ISO string as a query parameter, and the query doesn't work if the time is set to anything other than midnight.

Comment: It's more likely that your query needs the *UTC equivalent of the start or end of the local day*, which would probably not be aligned to UTC midnight, but I answered for what you asked below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the current UTC date at midnight:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setUTCHours(0);
d.setUTCMinutes(0);
d.setUTCSeconds(0);
d.setUTCMilliseconds(0);
var output = d.toISOString();
```

To get the current local date, with the time portion set to UTC midnight:

```
var d = new Date();
var ts = Date.UTC(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate());
var output = new Date(ts).toISOString();
```

As for which to use, think through your requirements very carefully, The current UTC date and the local date may indeed be two different days.

For example, when it's midnight (00:00) October 27th in UTC, it's 8:00 PM on October 26th in New York.

Also, consider using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com), which makes operations like either of these much easier with the `startOf('day')` and `.utc()` functions.

Comment: Thanks for this. Great explanations! In fact, UTC was what I was after. Think I'm going to opt for the moment.js option `moment().startOf('day').toISOString()`, as I'm already using that particular library. Thanks once again!